# Netty writeAndFlush returns false

Tags: netty

In what circumstances writAndFlush function in netty returns false. How can we debug it? Do I need to enable something to write on a channel? I also checked the channel and it is writable

Thanks,
Adib

Answer (score 2):

`writeAndFlush` returns a `ChannelFuture` and never a boolean value. You can register a listener to this `ChannelFuture` to see when the operation completes. You can check the success of the operation by the method `Channelfuture.isSuccess()`. Documentations here: https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/Channel.html#writeAndFlush-java.lang.Object- and https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/Future.html#isSuccess--